# lm behavior with mixed categorical and continuous variables

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

I'm confused about some of `lm`'s behavior in R and could use some clarification.

I'm trying to extract coefficients and confidence intervals for a given outcome for a set of mixed continuous, ordinal, and categorical variables.

Given data that looks like:

```
dat1 <- data.frame("a" = rnorm(n = 150, mean = 1, sd = 0.5),
                   "b" = rnorm(n = 150, mean = 10, sd = 1),
                   "c" = sample(x = c("cat", "dog", "weasel"),
                                size = 150,
                                replace = TRUE),
                   "d" = sample(x = c("blue", "orange", "red"),
                                size = 150,
                                replace = TRUE),
                   "e" = sample(c(1,10,100),
                                size = 150,
                                replace = TRUE))
```

I would expect a call to `lm` with `+0` in the formula to give me coeffecients for the none factorizable columns, and the categories for the factorizable columns. But it only returns all categories for the first column.

i.e.

```
mod1 <- lm(formula = a ~ . + 0,
           data = dat1)
# Call:
# lm(formula = a ~ . + 0, data = dat1)
# 
# Coefficients:
#          b        ccat        cdog     cweasel     dorange        dred           e  
# -0.0148532   1.0513402   1.0598578   0.9888098   0.1199336  -0.0142396   0.0009504
```

What changes to my `formula` would i need to return coefficients for all categories for all categorical columns?

Comment: Note that it gives you the all the categories for the first categorical variable, `c`m and all but one of the categories for the later categorical variable(s), `d`. Essentially you have made `c = cat` your intercept. In fact, if you run `mod0 <- lm(formula = a ~ ., data = dat1)` and compare, you'll see that the intercept coefficient of `mod0` and the `ccat` coefficient in `mod1` are the same.

Comment: There's not a change you need to make to the model formula, but you can set different contrasts. You can [read here about Helmert and sum-to-zero contrasts](https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Applied_Statistics/Book%3A_Learning_Statistics_with_R_-_A_tutorial_for_Psychology_Students_and_other_Beginners_(Navarro)/16%3A_Factorial_ANOVA/16.07%3A_Different_Ways_to_Specify_Contrasts).